# How can I change nodes order during building in device tree(fdt)

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, device-tree

I faced with problem: nodes in device tree after compiling I have reverse order when read final fdt file. For example, I have

```
parent_node@10000{
    <properties...>

     child_node2{
     <properties...> 
     };

     child_node1{
     <properties...> 
     };

     child_node0{
     <properties...> 
     };
};
```

Functions called in direct order to add nodes(checked with fdt-internals). What should I change in dt-compiler or fdt internals to make direct node order without permanent changing of dts content(swapping)? Like this

```
   parent_node@10000{
        <properties...>

         child_node0{
         <properties...> 
         };

         child_node1{
         <properties...> 
         };

         child_node2{
         <properties...> 
         };
    };
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: dtc has a `-s` option to sort nodes and properties before outputting, but I'm not sure which order it sorts them in.

Comment: I'm going to remove the [tag:c] tag, because it does not seem to be relevant to this question.

Comment: I need to sort not only for outputting, but for target fdt(dtb) file.

Comment: I'm not sure why you need the child nodes to end up in a particular order. Is the code that iterates through the child nodes of the parent node under your control? If so, you could define a property in the parent node that contains a comma-separated list of *phandle*s to the child nodes in the order you wish to process them. Your Linux code can call `of_parse_phandle()` to get the node at a particular index in the list. Start at index 0 in the list, then 1, etc. until it returns NULL, meaning you have reached the end of the list. (Don't forget to call `of_node_put()` on the returned nodes.)